# Is there some framework like .net in open source world?

Tags: .net, open-source, frameworks

all is in the title..
Is there some framework like .net in open source world?

I heard about zend framework is the same? Is not just for MVC designing?
For JAVA is there some framework as powerfull as Dotnet?

Comment: You need to make yourself a little more clear...

Comment: .NET is free and source code is viewable in Visual Studio (by dynamically downloaded pdb files) if enabled in options. Are you looking for a framework you can edit?

Comment: @Florian Reischl Yes but you need an IIS server to run .netwebApplication or Windows for .netWinform app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know very well Open source but i don't think a such framework exists..

Is Mono; A .Net implementation for Linux but i think Mono is not really "finished"..
And you certainly have other ones (particulary for JAVA) but i think .net is the most "unified" framework, others are hard to use and install because i think they are some pieces of a puzzle.

But Mono community is really growing (and it's a good thing!) ..

Answer (score 6):

Well there is open-source .NET implementation called [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)